# How to display text with label in Material UI?

Tags: input-fields, material-design, text

In a single page I would like to display Text Fields for user input and texts, which are static, but have labels. I tried to use the same text fields but with disabled attributes:

[image]

However, I am not happy that disabled fields are not bright enough. Actually those fields never meant to be editable, so it appears disabled state is not for them. I also searched some Material UI elements which is text with label, but couldn't find anything appropriate.

How Material UI is depicting elements with important text and label?

Comment: Ignoring Material Design, what's the user case to show the user the fields they cannot change?

Comment: @DarrylGodden To be able to compare visually the string (or just the beginning, end) with something external or copy it to clipboard.

Comment: This is not really a question for this site. Maybe ask it on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Disabled text fields sure is not the right choice. As i understand the text you need to display is not real text but unchangeable attributes that are important to the user.

In this case the label is more like an overline or secondary text. For consistency reasons you might have to align them so they have the same or a similar style to the labels.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your solution. Could you please show some wireframe demonstrating what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Hope you get it

[image]

Comment: It's not a hint I am trying to show. It's important piece of information.